# Internet Explorer 8 and jquery addEventListener

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener

I recently migrated my MVC 4 application from VS2010 to VS2012. I also migrated from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5 once everything was working, I upgraded the NuGet packages to the most recent stable versions.

Everything seemed to work fine, however I have now been informed that the app does not work using IE8 (nor IE7) although every other browser appears to be fine.

The following error appears:-

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' jquery-2.0.3.js, line 834 character 4

The generated HTML looks as follows:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/esri/css/esri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/menubar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2compact"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
```

My searches reveal that this method is not supported by IE8 but I am not sure where to go from here as the offending code is in the jquery file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using jQuery 2.0, which does not support IE8.

If you want to support IE8, you need to stick with jQuery 1.x.

Comment: any idea how to downgrade back to 1.x ?

Comment: @BlueChippy:  Install a specific version from the NuGet console.

Comment: Add event listener throws an error in IE8 in jQuery 1.x.

Comment: @AdonisSMU: What error? What code? You should ask a separate question.